# Visual Studio MFC CListCtrl Checkboxes - Spacebar

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I am developing an MFC application in Visual Studio 2008. I have a CListCtrl object that have checkboxes.
I am wondering if there is a simple way to have the spacebar toggle all highlighted items. Right now, on a spacebar down event I am doing this:

```
void toggleSelect()
{
    POSITION pos = m_cListCtrl.GetFirstSelectedItemPosition();
    while(pos)
    {
        int index = m_cListCtrl.GetNextSelectedItem(pos);
        BOOL check = m_cListCtrl.GetCheck(index);
        m_cListCtrl.SetCheck(index, !check);
    }
}
```

This would work if it wasn't for what I believe to be default behavior of the spacebar when a single item is highlighted(the checkbox is toggled automatically when a single item is selected). The problem with this code is that there is always one checkbox that is un-toggled. This is because of the default behavior of the spacebar toggling the single item that is selected. Is there anyway to disable the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Once you handle multiple selection check state, you allow list control handle check state toggle after it is set in your code.
You have to modify your code.
I just presume that you are handling LVN_KEYDOWN message. (**Is toggleSelect global? Why?**)

```
void CYourDlgClass::OnLvnKeydownList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLVKEYDOWN pLVKeyDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVKEYDOWN>(pNMHDR);

    if(VK_SPACE == pLVKeyDown->wVKey && m_cListCtrl.GetSelectedCount() > 1)
    {
            toggleSelect();
            *pResult = 1;
            return;
    }

    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
}

void CYourDlgClass::toggleSelect() 
{ 
    POSITION pos = m_cListCtrl.GetFirstSelectedItemPosition(); 
    while(pos) 
    { 
            int index = m_cListCtrl.GetNextSelectedItem(pos); 
            BOOL check = m_cListCtrl.GetCheck(index); 
            m_cListCtrl.SetCheck(index, !check); 
    } 
}
```

Setting *pResult to 0 you indicate that message was handled and no further handling is needed. 
I would suggest deriving class from CListCtrl and handle WM_KEYDOWN in similar manner:

```
void CMultiCheckListCtrl::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    if(VK_SPACE == nChar && GetSelectedCount() > 1)
    {
            POSITION pos = GetFirstSelectedItemPosition(); 
            while(pos) 
            { 
                    int index = GetNextSelectedItem(pos); 
                    BOOL check = GetCheck(index); 
                    SetCheck(index, !check); 
            } 
            return;
    }

    CListCtrl::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, John.
I didn't think about overriding the key down event. It's working great now :)